# SQL запрос, что-то не так с подстановкой

Tags: sql, inner-join

Добрый вечер! Имеется запрос, который выводит клиентов, которые посетили 2 страны 2 раза. Выглядит он вот-так:

```
SELECT client_id as "Клиент"
FROM (
    SELECT client_id, country_id
    FROM zakaz
    GROUP BY client_id, country_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t1
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

При попытке подставить вместо `id` фио, выдает ошибку. Вот, что делаю:

```
SELECT client.client_fio as "Клиент"
FROM (
    SELECT client.client_fio, zakaz.country_id
    FROM client INNER JOIN client.client_id = zakaz.zakaz_id
    GROUP BY client.client_fio, zakaz.country_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t1
GROUP BY client.client_fio
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: `FROM client INNER JOIN client.client_id = zakaz.zakaz_id` должен быть `FROM client INNER JOIN zakaz ON client.client_id = zakaz.zakaz_id`  И на будущее сообщение об ошибке то же пишите, оно иногда говорит где проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ON client.client_id = zakaz.zakaz_id
```

Надо бы исправить на

```
ON client.client_id = zakaz.client_id
```

Ибо.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил запрос:

```
SELECT t1.client_fio as "Клиент"
FROM (
    SELECT client.client_fio, zakaz.country_id
        FROM client INNER JOIN client.client_id = zakaz.zakaz_id
        GROUP BY client.client_fio, zakaz.country_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.client_fio
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Ошибка в том, что внешний SELECT знает только о таблице t1 и ничего не знает о client.

Comment: А ничего что таблица zakaz участвующая в списках выборки отсутствует в from и join ?

Comment: Поправил, ошибок нет, но теперь ничего не выдает, а с idшниками - выводит одного человека. Как такое возможно?)